# CreateSemaphore Library for WinCE 5.0

Tags: windows-ce, semaphore

Building a WinCE 5.0 application to use a semaphore. The function I am using to create the semaphore is CreateSemaphore(). The problem is that the application cannot be linked because there is not reference to the symbol CreateSemaphore. The Windows documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms885184) suggests that as long as I have nk.lib, the application should build. The problem is this library is no where to be found. I am also using the standard sdk for WinCE 5.0.

I have searched for the nk.lib library, but have not been able to find it.

Any thoughts on where this library is or if there is an alternative? I know this stuff is really old, but I am hoping someone knows where I can find this library.

EDIT: I figured I should add the link error:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateSemaphoreA referenced in function _Syn_System_Semaphore_initialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CE 5.0, CreateSemaphore is exported by coredll, so you'll need to link with `coredll.lib`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Carsten, however, the following is in my link script "/NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib coredll.lib corelibc.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib commctrl.lib".

Comment: Ah, seeing the linker error it looks like the project does not have UNICODE defined. In that case winbase.h #define's CreateSemaphore as CreateSemaphoreA but that function does not exist in Windows CE. Add UNICODE to your list of preprocessor definitions and it should look for CreateSemaphoreW instead (and hopefully find it, in coredll)

Comment: I forgot to reply, Carsten you were correct. I ended up doing a dump on coredll.lib and found the CreateSemaphoreW call and updated it. Thanks for all your help!